# Forcing some \section text to not be capitalized

Tags: capitalization

I have a document with the configuration below. I tried to use \MakeLowercase to force some text inside some sections to not be capitalized, but I'm get a warning (figure below). I would like to know how to solve this.

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,       
    openright,   
    twoside,    
    a4paper,     
    chapter=TITLE, 
    section=TITLE,
    english,
    french,
    spanish,
    brazil, 
]{abntex2}


\usepackage{lmodern}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lastpage}       
\usepackage{indentfirst}        
\usepackage{color}          
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}    
\usepackage{microtype}          
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref} 
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo}

\section{This is my title \MakeLowercase{this cannot be capitalized!} foo bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a solution which works with `hyperref`. If `hyperref` is not loaded you can just use `\lowercase` like this: `\section{Foo \lowercase{no upper case} bar}`

If `hyperref` is loaded this results in a warning ("Token not allowed in a PDF string...") and because of this we have to additionally use `\texorpdfstring`.  I defined a `\titlelowercase` macro for this usage. Now you'd have to use `\section{Foo \titlelowercase{no upper case} bar}`:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,       
    openright,   
    twoside,    
    a4paper,     
    chapter=TITLE, 
    section=TITLE,
    english,
    french,
    spanish,
    brazil, 
]{abntex2}


\usepackage{lmodern}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lastpage}       
\usepackage{indentfirst}        
\usepackage{color}          
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}    
\usepackage{microtype}          
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{hyperref}% hyperref is loaded by the class abntex2
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref} 
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}

\newcommand\titlelowercase[1]{\texorpdfstring{\lowercase{#1}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}

\section{This is my title \titlelowercase{this cannot be capitalized!} foo bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might as well use `\MakeTextLowercase` instead of `\lowercase`. It is provided by the `textcase` package (which is loaded by `abntex2` as well) and should handle some characters `\lowercase` doesn't (as far as I know).

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 2):

The class uses the `textcase` provided command `\MakeTextUppercase` for uppercasing the titles. This allows to use `\NoCaseChange` for parts you don't want to be capitalized.

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,       
    openright,   
    twoside,    
    a4paper,     
    chapter=TITLE, 
    section=TITLE,
    english,
    french,
    spanish,
    brazil, 
]{abntex2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{lmodern}
% other packages
% ...

\usepackage{hyperref} % should be last

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo}

\section{This is my title \NoCaseChange{this cannot be capitalized!} foo bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Loading `hyperref` last has no effect, it is already loaded by `abntex2`.

Comment: @Skillmon That's bad of them. `;-)`

Comment: I know, it's just something I found out while tinkering for my answer.